# phalcon email filter not work

Tags: phalcon, email-validation

Here's the code which is not working:

```
$email = $this->request->get('emailFromPost','email','');
```

What I want is getting a right validated email variable `$email`. While it's not working anyhow. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Filters are sanitizing your input, they do not validate it. Can you provide sample email addresses that you want to test?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a starter on Phalcon. So I can't catch your meaning. In my code example, I post a emailFromPost variable like 'test'. And I got $email as 'test'. I hope I can get $email as false.

Comment: By sanitizing I mean that it will filter unwanted data, for examples you can check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/phalcon/4917/filtering-and-sanitizing/17367/convenient-in-model-sanitizing#t=201608160647303667478 If you want returned as false you have to use the validation as suggested by Daison below.

Comment: Thank you so much. Gotcha now. Maybe Daison's solution is the best while I think it's a little complex. Can I just use another way:`filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` instead?

Comment: Well depends on what you need. If you have a form you should use [Phalcon forms](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/forms.html)

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Learning the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this kind of way:

```
use Phalcon\Validation;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Email;
...

$validation = new Validation;
$this->add('email', new Email(['message' => 'Email is not valid']));


if (count($messages = $validation->validate($data)) {
   // iterate $messages
   foreach ($messages as $message) {
       echo $message."\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: THX, I know it's working in this way. While I'm wondering why the email filter not works?